# PSQL how to have a recursive query with a variable parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need a query in SQL/PSQL that gives me a hierarchical relation of a specifiable parent.

I tried just a recursive query but I can't specify the first parent, then I tried putting the whole CTE expression in a function and finally I tried using a declared variable and redeclare it anytime I use the query.

```
DECLARE @procura = null;

WITH RECURSIVE hierarquia (procura) AS (
    SELECT categoria, super_categoria
    FROM
    CONSTITUIDA
    WHERE
    super_categoria = @procura
    UNION
    SELECT c.categoria, c.super_categoria
    FROM
    CONSTITUIDA c
    INNER JOIN hierarquia h ON h.categoria = c.super_categoria
) SELECT
*
FROM hierarquia;
```

Note:
CONSTITUIDA has 2 columns, categoria and super_categoria which are, respectively, the child and parent.

I want to specify a parent of CONSTITUIDA and it should return all children of that parent, at all recursion depths.

Comment: Oracle uses `CONNECT BY` for hierarchical queries

Comment: Postgres does not support variables in SQL. But you can't use `=` for NULL values anyway. You need `where super_categoria IS NULL`

Comment: `psql` is the name of the command line client. The database is called PostgreSQL or just Postgres